# Simple while-loop doesnt work

Tags: java, android, while-loop

I got a little problem. I think the solution is very simple but unfortunately I can't find it. I hope someone can help me
I  got a while-loop who has to count up to ten and write the number into a TextView.
It still doesn't work ...
Thanks for your help!
Here is the code:

```
package de.androidnewcomer.animation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.attr.button;
import static de.androidnewcomer.animation.R.id.textView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView ball=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ball);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            count();
            break;
    }
}
private void count() {
    TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    int i;
    i=1;
    while(i<10) {
        i++;
        textView.setText(i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ah, the goold old "doesn't work" issue description, so everyone knows _exactly_ what the issue is. But I actually have a guess: you hope to see a  count to ten and not just the ten the method is done? If so: do research.

Comment: what is the text display in textview?

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: Thanks for all this answers. I got the right output at the TextView now but its like Tom says: The output is only 10 - the end of the method. I researched and found the I can't use thread.sleep in the main Thread. But I thought the method is not in the onCreate Methode - is it? Or what's wrong again? Thanks for all helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textView.setText(..) needs a string object, but you use a int. You have to convert your int into a string with the following possible options:

1. You can use **String.valueOf(i)**: `textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));`
2. You can use **Integer.toString(i)**: `textView.setText(Integer.toString(i));`
3. You can use the **empty string literal**: `textView.setText("" + i);`

I prefer the last option. With your code, it should looks like the following code:

```
private void count() {
   TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
   int i;
   i=1;
   while(i<10) {
       i++;
       textView.setText("" + i);
       try {
           Thread.sleep(200);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

You can use a for loop instead of a while loop, like the following code:

```
private void count() {
   TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

   for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){ // From 1 to 10
       textView.setText("" + i);
       Thread.sleep(200); 
   }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with what kind of loop it is.

Answer (score 1):

Using setText() with an integer value is for setting a string resource reference. To set the text itself, you have to provide a string: Use `setText("" + i);` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CountDown because you are blocking the main thread

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(2000 /*amount*/, 200/*step*/) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           textView.setText("what ever you want");    
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setText("Done");
        }
    };
countDownTimer.start();
```